# Is there any plausible way to block certain web browsers from my website?

Tags: browser

If ideologically I oppose to the policies of a certain browser's ​developers (I think that the browser harms the users), can I somehow block that browser from accessing my website?

I would assume that such block would have to be backend, frontend won't help here, but can backend languages such as PHP/Ruby/C++/Python, etc. really help for that sake?

Comment: Easy solution would seem to have JavaScript load content only if the viewer claims to be the browsers you'd support.  It wouldn't be hard for someone to bypass such an inconvenience, but that's probably not a problem for you.

Comment: This question's concern isn't about security, it's about the OP opposing the browser itself. Is this not off topic? Even if the concern was security, I'm struggling to see why this isn't being asked on SO (where this exact question is answered multiple times).

Answer (score 3):

Your server can look at the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header in the HTTP request that the client sends to the server.  This header typically contains information about the user agent that made the request - i.e. if the request originated from a web browser, then the user agent information will generally contain the vendor and version of the browser.  So, your server can respond conditionally based on what the client sends in this header.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent for more info, and for examples of user agent strings for a number of widely used browsers.

However, be aware that the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` header is populated by the client.  Therefore, this header cannot be trusted, as it can easily be forged by the client.